# Fit 3d ellipsoid to a distribution of 3d points?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, computational-geometry, mcmc

I have a number of points in 3d space (cartesian x,y,z) and would like to fit a ellipsoid 
to that in order to determine the axis ratios. The issue here is that I have a distribution of points (not points on a surface), and the solutions to this problem mainly consider the points on a surface. Also would this fit be iterative (like some optimize or mcmc type method), I work in Python.

The code i am using was given in this answer: [Python: fit 3D ellipsoid (oblate/prolate) to 3D points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58501545/python-fit-3d-ellipsoid-oblate-prolate-to-3d-points)

But this does not work for me ( I think it was meant for points on the surface of an ellipsoid). But I have more density distribution of points rather than surface points.

Comment: Hi Warrenmovic. Could you help us by giving us a little more of context? Your series of points, and the code you have so far? It will maximize the help you can get from the community.

Comment: without more informaion about your probelm its hard to give you an answer but here's a couple links [leaast squares fitting of ellipsoid](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1982-21702015000200329) or depending on your data [Principle Component Analysis](https://towardsdatascience.com/pca-using-python-scikit-learn-e653f8989e60) might be a better match. I have used a variant of PCA for ellipsoid fitting in the past but the data set was particularly suited to it.